# Routes for reminders

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I have a controller with just a few actions, not the whole 7 RESTful actions situation. Here's what I have so far for routing:

```
Snip::Application.routes.draw do
  get "appointment_reminder_responses/confirmation_thanks", to: "appointment_reminder_responses#confirmation_thanks"
  get "appointment_reminder_responses/declination_thanks", to: "appointment_reminder_responses#declination_thanks"
  get "appointment_reminder_responses/:hash", to: "appointment_reminder_responses#create", as: :create_appointment_reminder_response
end
```

I think there certainly has to be a way to express this in a more DRY way, but but I'm not sure how that might go.

Answer (score 3):

Not a lot to review,

obviously the most repeated part of your code is `appointment_reminder_responses`, if you create a variable called `root` and then built your routes with concatenations like 
`root + "/confirmation_thanks"` then that would be a good start.

Furthermore you create a function that takes a string and modifies so that 
`"xxx/zzzz/yyyy"` becomes `"xxx/zzz#yyyy"` and use that function for the first 2 routes.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have your code or your requirements, you can take this with a grain of salt.

Even if there are certainly cases where REST cannot be applied, it seems that you have some sort of entity: `AppointmentReminderResponse` that you need to create with user information and then you need to give some sort of feedback to the user.

First of all, if you're modifying the state of a model, it's better to use `post` for the `#create` action. If you are not, you'd better use the action name `#new` (or something else) to avoid possible confusions, because of Rails conventions.

Another thing is, if you have an entity that you need to input some information (`new`), and based on that you will create a document or not (`create`), and finally you'll give the user some feedback, you could use a RESTful controller and routes for it (even if you don't need the 7 actions).

Having `:hash` as the key to get the Response should not be a problem.

I think you could write something like this:

```
resources appointment_reminder_responses, only: [:new, :create] do
  get :confirmation_thanks, to: :confirmation_thanks
  get :declination_thanks, to: :declination_thanks
end
```

Are you planning to show information from the `AppointmentReminderResponse` to the `confirmation_thanks` action? If so, you could go a bit further and consider that action like the `show` action for that `AppointmentReminderResponse`, and you'd have:

```
resources appointment_reminder_responses, only: [:new, :create, :show] do
  get :declination_thanks, to: :declination_thanks
end
```